# Exact same PHP only produces correct output once instead of twice

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, call

The plugin being used is The Events Calendar PRO, and the website is WordPress.

This code below isn't linking each 'Past Event' image to it's relevant event.  Instead it links back to the homepage.

The titles of the events do link to the correct place however, but the same code is being used in both places, so I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

```
<?php foreach( $events as $event ) : ?>
<div class="tribe-mini-calendar-event">
    <div class="list-info">
        <div class="tribe-events-event-image">
            <a href="<?php tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>"><?php echo tribe_event_featured_image( $event, 'medium' ); ?></a>
        </div>
        <h2 class="tribe-events-title"><a href="<?php tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>"><?php echo $event->post_title; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="tribe-events-duration">
            <?php echo date_i18n( get_option('date_format' ), strtotime( $event->EventStartDate ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

======================== UPDATE

The HTML Page Generates this for past event

```
      <div class="tribe-events-event-image">
        <a href="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/event/fimbulwinter-mmxiv/"></a>
        <a href="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/"><img width="212" height="300" src="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fimbulwinterMMXIV-212x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Fimbulwinter MMXIV" srcset="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fimbulwinterMMXIV-212x300.jpg 212w, http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fimbulwinterMMXIV-768x1087.jpg 768w, http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fimbulwinterMMXIV-724x1024.jpg 724w, http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/fimbulwinterMMXIV.jpg 851w"
          sizes="(max-width: 212px) 100vw, 212px"></a>
      </div>
```

While it generates this for UPCOMING TOURS

```
    <div class="tribe-events-event-image">
      <a href="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/event/between-the-buried-and-me-nz-tour-2016/">
      <img width="212" height="300" src="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BTBM-212x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="BTB&amp;M" srcset="http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BTBM-212x300.jpg 212w, http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BTBM-768x1086.jpg 768w, http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BTBM-724x1024.jpg 724w, http://touring.valhallatavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BTBM.jpg 1500w"
        sizes="(max-width: 212px) 100vw, 212px"></a>
    </div>
```

So there is a homepage link being thrown in by the image function...

Comment: Your HTML page generates two anchor links... one with the proper link and the other which redirects to the home page

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to fix. The HTML is outputted by the PHP above. Same PHP, different output. I don't understand.

Comment: Got it http://stackoverflow.com/a/35263588/4244623

Comment: TIP of the time ;) We should always tidy up our code to prevent wastage of time and precious headaches ;)

Comment: Excuse me? It's not even my code. Go tidy your own code... ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function tribe_event_featured_image requires a boolean parameter for a link. Because I wasn't giving it a true or false value it then was producing a link to the homepage. It placed that link within my own link thereby cancelling it out. I amended my code as follows:

I replaced

```
<?php tribe_event_featured_image( $event, 'medium' ); ?>
```

with

```
<?php tribe_event_featured_image( $event, $size = medium, $link = false ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change ::::
From `<?php tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>` :::: to `<?php echo tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>`

```
<?php foreach( $events as $event ) : ?>
<div class="tribe-mini-calendar-event">
    <div class="list-info">
        <div class="tribe-events-event-image">
            <a href="<?php echo tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>"><?php echo tribe_event_featured_image( $event, 'medium' ); ?></a>
        </div>
        <h2 class="tribe-events-title"><a href="<?php echo tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>"><?php echo $event->post_title; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="tribe-events-duration">
            <?php echo date_i18n( get_option('date_format' ), strtotime( $event->EventStartDate ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Try This Code 2**

```
<?php foreach( $events as $event ) { ?>
<div class="tribe-mini-calendar-event">
    <div class="list-info">
        <div class="tribe-events-event-image">
            <a href="<?php echo tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>">
                <?php echo tribe_event_featured_image( $event, 'medium' ); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <h2 class="tribe-events-title">
            <a href="<?php echo tribe_event_link( $event ); ?>">
                <?php echo $event->post_title; ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
        <div class="tribe-events-duration">
            <?php echo date_i18n( get_option('date_format' ), strtotime( $event->EventStartDate ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Still didn't work so have reverted to original code. You've helped me to trace the problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262554/exact-same-php-only-produces-correct-output-once-instead-of-twice/35262624?noredirect=1#comment58238647_35262554